# Razor equivalent of FromQuery attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, razor

I'm trying to build a simple page with a simple form with ASP.NET using a Razor page, and can't work out how to handle a particular post-back. In particular (through factors outside of my control) I'm getting a post-back with a single query parameter that is lowercase and kebab-case, in a regular MVC page I could use the `FromQuery` attribute, but it doesn't appear to work in this instance as with or without the attribute I get `null` passed to `OnPostAsync` each time. An example to illustrate this issue follows:

**Example.cshtml**

```
@page
@model my_namespace.Pages.ExampleModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Example Title";
}

<h2>Example</h2>

<form method="post">
    <!--- In actual code I don't have control of the name, so this is for illustrative purposes. --->
    <input type="text" name="kebabbed-name"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Example.cshtml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace my_namespace.Pages
{
    public class ExampleModel : PageModel
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        // This method is hit as expected, but the parameter is always null.
        // Changing the input name to something like "sample" and this parameter to match works however.
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string kebabbedName)
        {
            // Handling of the Post request
            return Page();
        }
}
```

So what I'm looking for is some way to process the postback with that kebabbed-name as a parameter - any solution would be welcomed.

Comment: *but it doesn't appear to work in this instance* be specific ... do you get any error or the model not binded properly?

Comment: I get `null` through as the value each time despite the method being hit each time. I've updated the question accordingly to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like Razor pages could process *kebabbed-names* automagically, however you can create a property in your `PageModel` class with a custom name that should bind to the postback value.

```
// For GET request
// [BindProperty(Name = "kebabbed-name", SupportsGet = true)]

// For POST request
[BindProperty(Name = "kebabbed-name")]
public string kebabbedName { get; set; }
```

Comment: That's annoying, though as you usually control them yourself I can see that it usually isn't an issue. I've tried your solution, and it works as intended. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I don't see this as a common use case. It's probably only useful when requests to your back end come from a front end you have no control of.

Comment: That's basically the situation I'm in - a drop in control via javascript from a trusted external source controls the data to post.